# Saved for loop output is different to that in console - R

Tags: r, for-loop, statistics, vegan

I am trying to save the classification success rates of the `CAPdiscrim` function from the `BiodiversityR` package. The vignette for `CAPdiscrim` (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/BiodiversityR/versions/2.7-2/topics/CAPdiscrim) gives an example on how to obtain the classification success rates:

```
library(BiodiversityR)
library(vegan)
library(MASS)
data(dune)
data(dune.env)

for (mseq in 1:14) {
    CAPdiscrim.result <- CAPdiscrim(dune~Management, data=dune.env, 
        dist="bray", axes=2, m=mseq)
}
```

This automatically prints the classification success percentages in the console eg.

```
Overall classification success: 40 percent
BF (n=3) correct: 0 percent
HF (n=5) correct: 40 percent
NM (n=6) correct: 33.3333333333333 percent
SF (n=6) correct: 66.6666666666667 percent
```

However when calling the `CAPdiscrim.result` object outside the loop, it produces the actual `CAPdiscrim` results eg (`str(CAPdiscrim.result`)).

```
List of 14
 $ PCoA        : num [1:20, 1:2] -0.3547 -0.2946 -0.0728 -0.0693 -0.3071 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:20] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. ..$ : NULL
 $ m           : int 14
 $ tot         : num 4.3
 $ varm        : num 107
 $ group       : Factor w/ 4 levels "BF","HF","NM",..: 4 1 4 4 2 2 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ CV          : Factor w/ 4 levels "BF","HF","NM",..: 1 2 4 4 3 2 2 1 1 2 ...
 $ percent     : num 40
 $ x           : num [1:20, 1:3] 7.64 0.18 9.43 8.88 -1.93 ...
```

etc. etc.

I feel I have tried everything to save the exact output that is printed in the console at the time of running the `for loop`. I have tried creating empty `list`s, empty `data.frame`s, binding the results. I just CANNOT figure out how to store it! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That code should be reproducible? Yes, I just want to save the strings. Even if it is overwriting, I would be able to obtain the last string alone. But what I get is the actual CAPdiscrim result, i.e. the whole statistical output.

Comment: Sorry, this is reproducible. I had a different error that I misinterpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those strings are being written out to the console via `cat()` during the function call. If you want to grab those values, use `capture.output`. For example

```
myout<-lapply(1:14, function(mseq) {
    msg <- capture.output(
      CAPdiscrim.result <- CAPdiscrim(dune~Management, data=dune.env, 
        dist="bray", axes=2, m=mseq), 
    type="output")
    list(msg=msg, result=CAPdiscrim.result)
})
```

This will capture the results and the strings in the list. You can get at the strings with

```
myout[[1]]$msg
```

for example.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is great.

Answer (score 1):

The for-loop will only retain the last CAPdiscrim.result of the mseq value, while overwriting the first 13 results in the loop.

Instead of losing them, use lapply instead

```
CAPdiscrim.result <- lapply(1:14, function(mseq){
                     CAPdiscrim(dune~Management, data=dune.env, 
                     dist="bray", axes=2, m=mseq)
                     })
```

This will generate a list of 14 results, each for each mseq value.

If what you are interested in is the console output for the classification success, then the easiest way to do it is to sink the console output as a text file.

```
sink("output_text.txt")
for (mseq in 1:14) {
      CAPdiscrim.result <- CAPdiscrim(dune~Management, data=dune.env, 
                                dist="bray", axes=2, m=mseq)
      }
sink()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I marked the other answer as correct as I can continue to manipulate the data in R that way. Cheers